# Macro in proc download for many files

Tags: server, download, sas

I am downloading many txt file from a server. I can do one file at a time successfully. But the I have a list of many paths of files in data A. I try to create macro variables from paths such as " /abc/11551.txt, /abc/1832555.txt, /abc/18355557.txt", but the program return error. Could anyone please help me?

```
    data B ;
    set A;
    length link link2 $ 500;
    link=substr(Name, 1);
    link2= cats('/abc/', link);
    keep link2;
    run;
    
    
    %let abc=server name;
    options comamid=TCP remote=abc;
    signon username=user password="xyz";
    
    rsubmit;
    
    * working well
    proc download infile="/abc/000009.txt"
    outfile="E:/test1.txt";


* not working

ERROR: Physical file does not exis

%let link3=link2;
proc download infile="&link3"
outfile="E:/&link3";
run;
```

Comment: Is there a file named `link2`  (without any extension) on the remote machine or not?  What was the purpose of the data step?  The variable LINK2 in the dataset B has nothing to do with the macro variable LINK3 that you hardcoded to the string link2.

Comment: The link 2 contains path of files that I want to download. There is no link2 on remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the intent was to download the file(s) listed in the dataset B then first move the dataset to the remote server.

Then you can use that data to generate PROC DOWNLOAD code.

```
rsubmit;
  proc upload data=b out=b; run;
  data _null_;
    set b;
    call execute(catx(' '
     ,'proc download infile=',quote(trim(link2))
     ,'outfile=',quote(cats('E:/test',_n_,'.txt'))
     ,';run;'
    ));
  run;
endrsubmit;
```

I don't see how macro code would help with this problem.

Comment: Excellent help, It works very well. How can I assign the outfiles in Folder 'E:/ test' with the same names as in Link2. Your codes give me the file name as' test1.txt, test2.txt.'

Comment: The same way you make LINK2.

Comment: Sorry Tom. I made a change to the code  outfile=',quote(cats('E:', link2) )). But it turns out error "Physical file does not exist" .I aslo change the Path to the remote server then got the same error." E:\wrdslin\0000029534-09-000025.txt.
ERROR: Download function terminated. The file created may be unusable
thank you very much!

Comment: Create the dataset with the calculated paths. Print it or view it with some browser to confirm you have generated proper names.  Remember with PROC DOWNLOAD the INFILE names have to be valid on the machine where the remote SAS session is running and the OUTFILE names have to be valid on the machine where the local SAS session is running.  The local SAS session might not be running on the personal computer you are using to type to code.  The names need to be valid on the machine were SAS itself is running not your browser or your Enterprise Guide application.

Comment: You have a great point, Tom. Finally, I have fixed the file names. I strongly appreciate your help. Your approach is fast and efficient for downloading a bulk of files. SAS Macro does not solve my problem. Many thanks again!